# rounding when doing calculation in physics

Tags: projectile, error-analysis, computational-physics

I came across a calculation for projectile motion in my physics book as follow:

$$r = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} = \sqrt{(4.5\,m)^{2} + (-1.2\,m)^{2}} = 4.7\,m$$

If I round the results in (1), (2) and (3), according to the significant figures:

$$\begin{align}
(4.5)^{2} = 20.25 &\Rightarrow 20 \quad(1)\\
(-1.2)^{2} = 1.44 &\Rightarrow 1.4 \quad(2)\\
\sqrt{(20) + (1.4)} = \sqrt{(21.4)} \approx 4.6260134 &\Rightarrow 4.6 \quad(3)\\
\end{align}$$

If I only round in (3), I got:

$$\sqrt{(20.25) + (1.44)} = \sqrt{(21.69)} \approx 4.65725240888 \Rightarrow 4.7,$$

which is consistent with the answer of the book.

*So why not just round at (3)?*

I originally think that if the 'not significant figures' got multiplied together, then they might be carried to the 'significant figures'.

*Why you make this guess? Isn't it a common sense?*

Because I trust people here, then I found the book, which is a college-textbook 13-th edition, has another example:

$$v = \sqrt{{v_x}^{2} + {v_y}^{2}} = \sqrt{(22.2\,\frac{m}{s})^{2} + (10.0\,\frac{m}{s})^{2}} = 24.4\,\frac{m}{s}$$

If I only round at (III):
$$\begin{align}
(22.2)^{2} &= 492.84 \quad (I)\\
(10.0)^{2} &= 100.00 \quad (II)\\
\sqrt{(492.84) + (100.00)} = \sqrt{(592.84)} &\approx 24.3483059 \Rightarrow 24.3 \quad (III),\\
\end{align}$$

which is not consistent with the book.

Is the book wrong? If it is wrong, skip the following question.

If not, what's the actually steps that works for both?

Appreciated.

Comment: "*I think that if I round numbers in each step the error would become smaller*" You expect the error to be *smaller* when you *change* the value to something else than what it was? Why would you think so??

Comment: What does "step" and "last one" mean when you say "*I only round at the last step*" and "*if I round only at the last one*". Do you means "digit"?

Comment: This is more of a math.se question

Comment: @N1ng what do you mean with "last step"? As the text is now I unfortunately can't understand it. Therefore the downwards, I'm afraid

Comment: @Doc I don't think it really is? Is it?

Comment: In physics (at least from my experience), rounding is often used starting from $10^{-3}$. As such, the answer of equation $(3*)$ is rounded to $24.35$ (plus you have two significant digits in the square values up above, try to keep the same precision all along).

This can lastly be written as $2.4$ but except if you have uncertainties on the second significant digit, don't round it in the general case.

Comment: I  believe that my answer addresses and provides more info on why your answer is incorrect.  Just because a digit isn't "signifigant" doesn't make it uncertain.

Comment: @JMac I agree but in any case, rounding is often for reading convention if the exact precision is not relevant. Less rounding is the better in any case.

Comment: I would also point out that it looks like the second answer is actually *wrong*. The correct answer is indeed 24.3483.... and thus rounds to 24.3, not 24.4. The book likely made a mistake - because the book is likely written by a physicist, and most of us see $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$ and consider the problem over!

Comment: If you and I were doing the same experiment, and you reported 24.4 m/s when I was expecting 24.3 m/s, I'd say that we *agreed*.  If I felt strongly about that final 0.3 I would express it by keeping an extra significant figure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rounding multiple times will make your answer less accurate.  This is known as [Round off error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) and should be fairly intuitive.

When you cut off a number you are changing the values in the operations.  The more you cut numbers off the more different the values will be.  As long as your original sources for the values are reliable, you will only be less accurate by rounding more times.

Significant figures (you mentioned in your edit you were using them) should only be applied after the math is all done.  It is the result of knowing you can only be as accurate as the least accurate value you've been given.  Doing this more doesn't make it more accurate.  In fact signinfigant figures doesn't make the answer more accurate either, it just makes it a better reflection of the information it was based on.

Comment: Very nice descriptive answer!

Comment: So I can make a conclusion that the book's wrong? I do follow your advice and I get $24.3$ instead of $24.4$.

Comment: @N1ng The book appears to be wrong (very slightly) on the second one.  The answer to that was 2.348...  I had a highschool math teacher who would have rounded that up to 2.35 and then 2.4; which is terrible practice.  So yes, they may have broken the rules themselves.  Your best bet is to only ever round at the end when possible (not always possible if using a 10 digit calculator or dealing with repeating or irrational decimals).  Their answer for the first question seems to be done properly though.

Comment: This also depends on how you were taught to do significant figures. I was taught "you write down all of the digits that you're certain about, plus one more digit which is a guess." In other words when you're measuring how long something is with a ruler, you might measure it as $21.27\text{ cm}$ reflecting the fact that it got most of the way through that  $2\text{ mm}$ mark but not quite all the way to the $3$: but I am also saying "it might have been 21.25 or 21.29, I don't know." If that is your standard then your "24.3 and 24.4" are both within each others' error margins.